# Unable to initiate a flow session with another node from a ScheduledFlow

Tags: corda

I am trying to initiate a flow session with another node from a ScheduledFlow. Below is the Scheduledstate definiton:

```
data class State(val a: Party,
                         val b: Party,
                         val instant: Instant,
                          val status: Status,
                          override val linearId: UniqueIdentifier = UniqueIdentifier(),
                          override val participants: List<AbstractParty> = listOf(a, b))
: LinearState, SchedulableState {

private val scheduledTime = instant
override fun nextScheduledActivity(thisStateRef: StateRef, flowLogicRefFactory: FlowLogicRefFactory): ScheduledActivity? {
    if (status != Status.COMPLETED) {
        return null
    } else {
        return ScheduledActivity(flowLogicRefFactory.create("com.example.flows.StartFlow", thisStateRef), scheduledTime)
    }
}}
```

Below is the StartFlow definiton:

```
@InitiatingFlow
@SchedulableFlow
class StartFlow(val ref: StateRef): FlowLogic<SignedTransaction?>(){

    @Suspendable
    override fun call(): SignedTransaction? {
        val notary = serviceHub.networkMapCache.notaryIdentities[0]
        val stateAndRef = serviceHub.loadState(stateRef = ref)
        val state = stateAndRef.data as State
        if (state.status != State.COMPLETED) {
            throw IllegalArgumentException("Cannot initiate transfer of ownership")
        }

        // Role decider:
        val parties = state.participants.sortedBy { it.owningKey.toBase58String() }
        if (ourIdentity == parties[0]) {
            val tx = TransactionBuilder(notary = notary)

            // add input states
            tx.addInputState(stateAndRef)

            // add output states
            tx.addOutputState(state.copy(status = Status.TRANSFERRED), ContractA.CONTRACT_ID)
            val command = Command(ContractA.Commands.Command1(), listOf(state.a.owningKey, state.b.owningKey))
            tx.addCommand(command)

            tx.verify(serviceHub)

            val partSignedTx = serviceHub.signInitialTransaction(tx)
            val counterparty = serviceHub.identityService.wellKnownPartyFromAnonymous(parties[1]) ?: throw IllegalStateException("Cannot resolve responding party")
            val counterPartySession = initiateFlow(counterparty)
            val fullySignedTx = subFlow(CollectSignaturesFlow(partSignedTx, setOf(counterPartySession)))

            return subFlow(FinalityFlow(fullySignedTx))
        }
        return null
    }
}
```

while testing the above flow, State object is created as follows:

```
State(a, b, Instant.now().plus(10), Status.COMPLETED)
```

StartFlow is not able to initiate the session with counter party and the code gets stuck there.

If the State is constructed as

```
State(a, b, Instant.now(), Status.COMPLETED)
```

The StartFlow is able to initiate session with counterparty and everything works fine.

What could be the issue here?

Comment: Can you check the logs of both the node running the initiating flow and the node running the responder flows and post the output here, please?

Comment: i did some close debugging and realised that below condition check was incorrect for deciding role
`if (ourIdentity == parties[0])`

Got it working by changing it to
`if (ourIdentity.owingkey == parties[0].owingkey)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As Nitesh reported, the condition check was incorrect for the deciding role. `ourIdentity == parties[0]` should have been `ourIdentity.owingkey == parties[0].owningkey`.

This is because `parties[0]` is of type `AbstractParty`. `ourIdentity` is of type `Party`. `AbstractParty` overrides `equals` as follows:

```
override fun equals(other: Any?): Boolean = 
    other === this || 
    other is AbstractParty && other.owningKey == owningKey
```

Thus the two objects were not considered equal.