# Corda initiating-flow-session-failed

Tags: corda

I am facing an issue while running flow tests involving scheduled states and flows.
States and flows are defined here: [Unable to initiate a flow session with another node from a ScheduledFlow](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53011893/unable-to-initiate-a-flow-session-with-another-node-from-a-scheduledflow/53066168#53066168)

Test nodes are setup like this:

```
@Before
fun setup() {
    mockNetwork = MockNetwork(listOf("com.example.states", "com.example.contracts", "com.example.flows", "com.example.schema"))
    a= mockNetwork.createNode(MockNodeParameters(legalName = CordaX500Name("NodeA", "London", "GB")))
    b= mockNetwork.createNode(MockNodeParameters(legalName = CordaX500Name("NodeB", "London", "GB")))
    c= mockNetwork.createNode(MockNodeParameters(legalName = CordaX500Name("NodeC", "London", "GB")))

    mockNetwork.runNetwork()
}
```

The test doesn't move ahead and gets stuck with below log:

```
[INFO ] 2018-08-24T07:49:19,739Z [Node thread-1] flow.[c833dc79-501e-4484-9c43-a6924b472542].initiateSession - Initiating flow session with party O=NodeB, L=London, C=GB. Session id for tracing purposes is SessionId(toLong=4256917187941908080). {}
```

How do i know if the NodeB mockednode has gone down and so unable to receive flow session? Surprisingly, the test works most of the time.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue got resolved by changing the network definition to `mockNetwork = MockNetwork(listOf("com.example.states", "com.example.contracts", "com.example.flows", "com.example.schema"), threadPerNode=true)`